# Finding file names (from a directory) in a file

Tags: python

I want to find if all the files of a certain type have been logged by my program. So essentially, I have a logfile with just the file names and then I use a function to run through the file to check if the file is present. Now the contents are huge but I did this in a crude way. Unfortunately, it's not working properly.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import signal
import shutil
import os, fnmatch


#open file to read
f=open("logs", "r") #files are stored in this directory
o=open("all_output_logs","w")
e=open("missing_logs",'w')


def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
        #ignore directories- ignore works, just uncomment. 
    #ignored = ["0201", "0306"]
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        #for dir in ignored:
           # if dir in dirs: 
                #dirs.remove(dir)
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)



    #here i log all the files in the output file to search in
for line in f:
    if line.startswith("D:"):
        filename = line
        #print line
        o.write(filename)

f.close()
o.close()
r.close()

i=open("all_output_logs","r")
#primitive search.. going through each file in the directory to see if its there in  the log file
for filename in locate("*.dll"):
    for line in i:
        if filename in i:
            count=count+1
            print count
        else:
            e.write(filename)
```

I do not see my dummy variable count being printed, and I only get one filename which is somehow in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is tha the lines in the file are read only in the first pass, and that a file object (`i` in your case) doesn't support the use of the `in` operator as you expect. You can change the code to something like:

```
lines = open("all_output_logs","r").readlines()
for filename in locate("*.dll"):
    for line in lines:
        if filename in line:
            count=count+1
            print count
        else:
            e.write(filename)
```

But it still would be inefficient and somewhat awkward.

Since you say that the log file is *"huge"* then you probably don't want to read it all into memory, so you'll have to *rewind* for each lookup:

```
f = open("all_output_logs","r")
for filename in locate("*.dll"):
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        if filename in line:
            count=count+1
            print count
        else:
            e.write(filename)
```

I left the `in` operator because you don't specify what each line of the log file contains. One would have expected `filename == line.strip()` to be the correct comparison.